# Why can't I call my function recursively?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile this code in order to reverse a string:

```
void reverse(char *str, int n)
{
    if (n==0 || n==1) {
        return;         //acts as quit
    } else {
        char i = str[0];    //1st position of string
        char j = str[n-1];  //Last position of string
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];    //Swap
        str[j] = temp;
        reverse(str[i+1],n-1);  // <-- this line
    }
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char *word = "hello";
    int n = sizeof word;

    reverse(word, n);
    std::cout << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler reports an error where I call `reverse()` recursively:

> invalid conversion from `char` to `char*` at `reverse(str[i+1], n-1)`.

Why?

Any advice on other issues in my code is also welcome.

Comment: Listen to the compiler before posting a question on SO. It's easy `reverse` takes as input a `char*` while you're feeding it a `char` (i.e., `str[i+1]`).

Comment: `str[i]` is not a `i`th "position" in the `str` string, it is a value stored there. I.e. `str[i+1]` is a `char`, compiler is right.

Answer (score 2):

`str[i+1]` is a character, not a pointer to a character; hence the error message.

When you enter the function, `str` points to the character you're going to swap with the `n`:th character away from `str`.
What you need to do in the recursion is to increment the pointer so it points to the next character.
You also need to decrease `n` by *two*, because it should be a distance from `str + 1`, not from `str`.
(This is easy to get wrong; see the edit history of this answer for an example.)

You're also using the characters in the strings as indexes into the strings when swapping.
(If you had the input `"ab"`, you would do `char temp = str['a']; str['a'] = str['b']; str['b'] = temp;`. This is obviously not correct.)
`str[0]` is not the position of the first character, it *is* the first character.

Use `std::swap` if you're allowed to, otherwise see below.

More issues: you shouldn't use `sizeof word`, as that is either 4 or 8 depending your target architecture - it's equivalent to `sizeof(char*)`.
You should use `strlen` to find out how long a string is.

Further, you should get a warning for

```
char *word = "hello";
```

as that particular conversion is dangerous - `"hello"` is a `const` array and modifying it is undefined.
(It would be safe if you never modified the array, but you are, so it isn't.)
Copy it into a non-const array instead:

```
char word[] = "hello";
```

and increase the warning level of your compiler.

Here's a fixed version:

```
void reverse(char *str, int n)
{   
    if(n <= 1) // Play it safe even with negative n    
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // You could replace this with std::swap(str[0], str[n-1])
        char temp = str[0];    //1st character in the string
        str[0] = str[n-1];    //Swap
        str[n-1] = temp;

        // n - 2 is one step closer to str + 1 than n is to str.
        reverse(str + 1, n - 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = "hello";
    // sizeof would actually work here, but it's fragile so I prefer strlen.
    reverse(word, strlen(word));
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Indexing `str[i]` and `str[j]` look wrong, too - I think they should be `str[0]` and `str[n-1]` respectively.

Comment: Ooh, and you need `n-2`, not `n-1`, or you always swap with the final character.

Comment: In addition, the original `main` function is passing `sizeof("hello")` to the reverse function.  This will reverse the terminating null character to the first character - and the output will be empty!

Comment: @Martin - the error is slightly different, as the original used `sizeof (char*)`, not `sizeof (char[6])`.  See my answer (which I wrote as molbdnilo was editing).

Comment: @TobySpeight: Oh grief!  So that would have either given "lleho" or undefined behaviour, depending on whether the OP compiled for 32 or 64 bits.  Joy!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to dissect your code, as if you'd posted over on [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com).  You did ask for other observations, after all...

Firstly,

```
char *word = "hello";
```

Your compiler should warn you that pointing a `char*` at a literal string is undefined behaviour (if not, make sure that you have actually enabled a good set of warnings.  Many compilers emit very few warnings by default, for historical reasons).  You need to ensure that you have a writable string; for that you can use a `char[]`:

```
char word[] = "hello";
```

The next line

```
int n = sizeof word;
```

has now changed meaning, but is still wrong.  In your original code, it was the size of a *pointer to `char`*, which is unlikely to be the same as the length of the word "hello".  With the change to `char[]`, it's now the size of an array of 6 characters, i.e. `6`.  The sixth character is the NUL that ends the string literal.  Instead of the `sizeof` operator, you probably want to use the `strlen()` function.

Moving on to `reverse()`:

You read characters from positions in the string, and then use those characters to index it.  That's not what you want, and GCC warns against indexing using plain `char` as it may be signed or unsigned.  You just want to index in one place, and your `i` and `j` are unnecessary.

Finally, the question you asked.  `str[i+1]` is the *character at position `i+1`*, but your function wants a pointer to character, which is simply `str+i+1`.  Or, since we worked out we don't want `i` in there, just `str+1`.

Note also that you'll need to subtract 2 from `n`, not `1`, as it will be used as a count of characters from `str+1`.  If you only subtract 1, you'll always be swapping with the last character, and you'll achieve a 'roll' rather than a 'reverse'.

---

Here's a working version:

```
void reverse(char *str, int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        // end of recursion
        return;         //acts as quit

    char temp = str[0];
    str[0] = str[n-1];    //Swap
    str[n-1] = temp;
    reverse(str+1,n-2);
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    char word[] = "hello";
    int n = std::strlen(word);

    reverse(word, n);
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```

---

We can make further changes.  For example, we could use `std::swap` to express the switching more clearly.  And we could pass a pair of pointers instead of a pointer and a length:

```
#include <utility>              // assuming C++11 - else <algorithm>

void reverse(char *str, char *end)
{
    if (end <= str)
        // end of recursion
        return;

    std::swap(*str, *end);
    reverse(str+1, end-1);
}
```

and invoke it with `reverse(word, word+n-1)`.

---

Finally (as I'm not going to mention `std::reverse()`), here's the idiomatic iterative version:

```
void reverse(char *str, char *end)
{
    while (str < end)
        std::swap(*str++, *end--);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use like this :

```
     reverse(&str[i+1],n-1);
```

pass address of the (i+1)th position not value.